# Not able to create a chrome extension out of a website I made with Google Apps Script and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-apps-script

Using scripts.google.com, I designed an HTML page wherein user can answer 8 questions and I wrote a piece of code to save that data directly to a Google Sheet. 
It's working like a charm and this is the first time I worked on HTML CSS in combination with Google Apps script.

To a step ahead, I tried to create a chrome extension out of it. I honestly know nothing about it. But the fact that my project is running fine, I am not able to understand why I am not able to make a extension out of it.

I read a few articles and did some research. I need help with creating the menifest file as I believe that's one of the reasons why my extension does not work even after loading the html file correctly. Secondly, I noticed that the script which I wrote in Google Apps Script is of .gs file format but all the articles say that it should be a .js file format. If anyone could guide me oon these aspects than I'd be really really happy :)

Comment: while my html is loading fine in the extension, it's not reacting to the input. I have a few codes running in the background, to capture timestamp, the answers ofcourse and form loading time. None of these actions are working. My extension looks like a body without soul...

Comment: Have you tried going over the [Chrome Extension Overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) ? There are several parts of a chrome extension and it requires understanding how an extension works.

Comment: Thank you for helping. I am currently stuck at the script part. Extension support page that you shared says that there should be a .js file but I have a .gs file since I wrote the script in Google Scripts. I want to know if that'll work. If it will work then I can really get into understanding the basics or else there's no point.

Comment: Figured this one out too. I authorized the use of Google Sheets in the menifest file and used the HTML elements of my webapp to push the data using that interface. Charm :)